# Emulating Photoshop color levels in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, image-processing

I'm making an app in which I need to make some photo effects similar to Instagram's effects. I was wondering if it's possible to somehow emulate the work of Photoshop's color levels in AS3.

I've tried using `AdjustColor`, `ColorMatrixFilter` and `ColorTransform` classes but desired image is very hard to achieve using those.

So does anyone have a solution easier than that? or maybe someone knows a library that I couldn't find on Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Joa's image processing library](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/imageprocessing-library/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this library: 
http://peternitsch.net/bitmapdata.js/
This is actually implemented in Javascript, but it's based on the Flash API. All You need is there. Or i can recommend Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Image Effects by Todd Yard.

[Flash API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) is another good resource for inspiration.

There is another good resource for pixel manipulation found here: http://evanw.github.com/webgl-filter/. This is done in WebGL but if your target API is still Flash, then you can easily transposed the GLSL language into Pixelbender and inject the shader 
into the Flash by making reference to the pbj file.

Answer (score 0):

Check Grant Skinner's [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) plugins, especially ColorMatrixFilter.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. TweenMax just gradually changes the properties I could use by hand.